# Core Data / Range Update

Tags: ios, ios4, core-data

Here is a simple mySQL request :

```
UPDATE myTable SET X=X-1 WHERE (X>100)
```

Now my question goes like this.
How would I write a similar request in Core Data ?

I am starting to find out my way in Core Data; but the last part of the above SQL order gives me problems in Core Data.

In other word : how do I handle the `WHERE (X>100)` part.

If the mySQL request concerned one record only, I would use some thing like this :

```
[matchItem setValue:VALUE forKey:@"X"];
```

But how do I do if is a range of records, like here, where I want to perform some actions for all records where X>100.

Comment: Some advice:Core Data is not SQL. Entities are not tables. Objects are not rows. Attributes are not columns. Relationships are not joins. Core Data is an object graph management system that may or may not persist the object graph and may or may not use SQL far behind the scenes to do so. Trying to think of Core Data in SQL terms will cause you to completely misunderstand Core Data and result in much grief and wasted time. In this case, you can't update records in a table because they don't logically exist in Core Data. Only the managed objects and their graph exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `NSPredicate` and add it to your `NSFetchRequest`.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
    @"X > %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:100]];
```

Iterate through your results array and set the value as appropriate.

```
for (NSManagedObject *match in resultsArray) {
    NSInteger newValue = [[match objectForKey:@"X"] intValue] +1;
    [match setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:newValue] forKey:@"X"];
}
```